# Less font-face src url contains font family

Tags: less, font-face

I just inherited an application and the less variable file is setup as follows.

```
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
@exampleFont: exampleFont, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-   serif;

@font-face {
  font-family: exampleFont; 
  src: url('@{icon-font-path}@{exampleFont}.ttf') format('truetype'); 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

compiled CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: exampleFont;
  src: url('../fonts/exampleFont, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

}

Does anyone know why the src url contains the url AND font family and when it is compiled it combines both and still works? I've never seen it done this way before.

Answer (score 1):

src should be
`src: url('@{icon-font-path}exampleFont.ttf') format('truetype');`

In the current code it has `@{exampleFont}` which would expand to the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example on how to use a mixin for Fonts in LESS:

https://github.com/MarcoHengstenberg/helpCSS/blob/master/help.css#L528-L547

On line 533 you have to replace weight and style with actual values for your regular font (400, normal).